# I am trying to fetch User data using userName in Spring JPA repository, but it always returns an empty list

Tags: spring, jpa, repository

I am using below code to fetch user information from MySQL database using username, but it always returns empty list.

```
 public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<User> findByUserNameIgnoreCase(String userName);
 }
```

The below method is in service class

```
public String login(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
    logger.info("Login request for customer {} with password {}", 
    loginDTO.getUserName(), loginDTO.getPassword());
    List<User> user = 
    userRepo.findByUserNameIgnoreCase(loginDTO.getUserName());
    if(user.isEmpty())
      return "Invalid";
    else
      return "Successful";
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Please add User and LoginDTO  class

Answer (score 0):

Trying findByUsernameIgnoreCase because Spring might treat it as User and Name instead of Username.